# How to open new subwindow from another subwindow in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I want to open one subwindow from another subwindow.That is, i m having one popup subwindow in that window i placed one button.If we click that button another popup subwindow should open. When i am trying this i m getting error that "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can only add windows inside application-level windows." Can anyone tell me how to solve this in vaadin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a reference to the main window for the application and add a subwindow to that.

```
yourCurrentSubWindow.getApplication().getMainWindow().addWindow(myNewSubWindow);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case I tried the same with a reference I pass to my CustomComponent and tried to add the window from there: refToApplicaiton.getMainWindow().addWindow(myNewSubWindow); but I get the same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Just a small correction to the previous solution:

```
yourCurrentSubWindow.getApplication().getMainWindow().addWindow(myNewSubWindow);
```

Those div-bases embedded child windows cannot contain sub-windows, but the main window (and any other top level native window) can.

Answer (score 1):

On Vaadin 7 this can be done as follows:

```
getUI().addWindow(myNewSubWindow);
```